# Как забрать background

Tags: css, background, border

Надо задать фон внутрь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block::after,
.block::before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block::before {
  top: 0;
}

.block::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.block__inner {
  position: relative;
  height: inherit;
}

.block__inner::after,
.block__inner::before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block__inner::before {
  left: 0;
}

.block__inner::after {
  right: 0;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(2) {
  top: -30px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(3) {
  left: -30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.corner:nth-child(2),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  right: -30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.corner:nth-child(2),
.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__inner">
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я сформировал правильно вопрос

Comment: Всё равно не понятно что значит "забрать", если вы хотите вставить фон, то посмотрите на стили `body`, думаю там ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: Мне нужно задать фон в середине элемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block::after,
.block::before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block::before {
  top: 0;
}

.block::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.block__inner {
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: url('https://www.syl.ru/misc/i/ai/427172/2871002.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: inherit;
}

.block__inner::after,
.block__inner::before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block__inner::before {
  left: 0;
}

.block__inner::after {
  right: 0;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  background-color: #333;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(2) {
  top: -30px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(1),
.corner:nth-child(3) {
  left: -30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.corner:nth-child(2),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  right: -30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.corner:nth-child(2),
.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.corner:nth-child(3),
.corner:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__inner">
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="corner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```